# Open a URL as a popup/Iframe in MS Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, direct-line-botframework

I have a Bot, as part of the conversation we will be sending a link on click of that need to open the page as a popup/in a Frame up on the MS Team window.

Bot is created using MS Bot framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using something called a ["Task Module"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-task-modules). Task Modules are basically framed popups inside Teams, and they can show either an Adaptive Card or a a web url, where you can host your own web content or even an iframe. As per the docs:

> Task modules allow you to create modal popup experiences in your Teams application. Inside the popup you can run your own custom HTML/JavaScript code, show an -based widget such as a YouTube or Microsoft Stream video or display an Adaptive card. They are especially useful for initiating and completing tasks or displaying rich information like videos or Power BI dashboards. A popup experience is often more natural for users initiating and completing tasks compared to a tab or a conversation-based bot experience.

Comment: (in my experience) Only https:// URIs in <a href=""> are supported in the Adaptive Cards in Microsoft Teams.

Be nice if Teams supported more URIs

Comment: Well, this is talking about hosting task modules, rather than <a> tags, but yes, it's httpS all around. It's be a recommendation for the longest time, even for internal company web traffic, to be more secure, and non-httpS sites are de-ranked by Google, for instance, so I'm not sure I'd advocate personally for http. Perhaps you're referring to something else? file:// paths perhaps? That's also not a good idea in Teams because they're (a) a bad idea (rather use something better than a file share) and (b) won't work all that well on a mobile, from home.

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow getting "Unable to reach app. Please try again.", when the pop is open. please help me here...

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow -  my case is I need to open a web page in a popup. I think we can achieve this using  new AdaptiveOpenUrlAction()
                    {
                        Title = "Task Module - Deeplink",
                        Url = new Uri(DeeplinkHelper.DeepLink)
                    } if you help me the c# code snippet pls.

Comment: Are you still getting the "unable to reach app"? If so, check that the domain of your website is listed as a trusted domain in your application manifest (i.e. in App Studio if you're using that, otherwise in the manifest json file directly if you're editing it raw)

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow Thank you. yes, add in the trusted domain. i was running from local machine using ngrok and add ngrok url.

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow No, after adding ngrok URL also getting "Unable to reach app. Please try again."

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it's been a busy week. I'm reading this again, and getting confused. What is it you're trying to display in your popup? Why would you need a deeplink? I don't think you can "deep link" to something inside of Teams, from within a Task module - they can only show Adaptive Cards, or a web frame hosted *outside* of Teams

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow Thank you issue got resolved. I am using Deeplink to show a popup with an external web page. Is there a way on close of the popup (using X button displaying on popup window), notification send to Bot.

Comment: oh, so it's your own deeplink into your own application, not an actual "Teams" Deep link? In any case, in a regular task module, closing it should send an event call back to the bot, I think.